# How to shrink color bar of heatmap plot to fit the dimension of the plot in Julia?

Tags: plot, julia

I have the following heatmap plot:

```
using DataFrames, Plots, Statistics, RDatasets

iris_df = dataset("datasets", "iris")
cor_mat = cor(Matrix(iris_df[:, 1:4]), dims=1)
col_names = names(iris_df)[1:end-1]
heatmap(
  col_names, col_names, cor_mat,
  rightmargin=20Plots.mm,
  leftmargin=10Plots.mm,
  aspect_ratio=:equal,
  size=(700, 700),
  title="Correlation heatmap between 4 features of the Iris dataset",
  xlabel="Features", ylabel="Features",
  colorbar_title="Correlation",
  color=:bluesreds,
  framestyle=:box,
  titlefont=font(12)
)
plot!(dpi=300)
```

[image]

How can I shrink it to fit the plot?
`Plots` version: `v1.37.2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With default `gr()` backend, use keyword argument: `lims=(0,4)`:

```
gr()

heatmap(
  col_names, col_names, cor_mat,
  aspect_ratio=:equal,
  size=(1000, 1000),
  title="\n"^6 * "Correlation heatmap between 4 features of the Iris dataset",
  xlabel="Features", ylabel="Features",
  colorbar_title="Correlation",
  color=:bluesreds,
  framestyle=:box,
  titlefont=font(15),
  lims=(0,4),
  dpi=300
)
```

[image]

Comment: Good, but not entirely correct. It shifts the title of the plot vertically far!

Comment: Just write your title as follows:

`title="\n"^6 * "Correlation heatmap between 4 features of the Iris dataset"`

Comment: Yes, now it's correct. I tried it on `pyplot`, and it also works. I updated my answer inspired by this one.

Answer (score 1):

using the `pyplot()` as the backend and moving the `dpi` inside of the `heatmap` function solves the problem:

```
pyplot()

heatmap(
  col_names, col_names, cor_mat,
  rightmargin=20Plots.mm,
  leftmargin=10Plots.mm,
  aspect_ratio=:equal,
  size=(700, 700),
  title="Correlation heatmap between 4 features of the Iris dataset",
  xlabel="Features", ylabel="Features",
  colorbar_title="Correlation",
  color=:bluesreds,
  framestyle=:box,
  titlefont=font(12),
  dpi=300
)
```

[image]

But when I try to save the figure using the `savefig` function, it saves the unshrinked version :)

---

**Update 12/20/2022**
Inspired by [Rafael's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74865411/11747148), using `lims = (0, 4)`* in the `heatmap` function on the `pyplot` backend solves the issue completely even in the result of `savefig`:

```
pyplot()

heatmap(
  col_names, col_names, cor_mat,
  aspect_ratio=:equal,
  size=(1000, 1000),
  title="Correlation heatmap between 4 features of the Iris dataset",
  xlabel="Features", ylabel="Features",
  colorbar_title="Correlation",
  color=:bluesreds,
  framestyle=:box,
  titlefont=font(15),
  lims=(0,4),
  dpi=300
)
```

[image]
*The reason behind `4` is the number of squares in the vertical axes is 4.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue once but with a regular plot, the fix that i did was to get the higher value of both 'x' and 'y' coordinates and make an initial plot like this:

```
toSave = plot([X],[Y])
```

Then pushed the plot that i wanted with

```
plot!()
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I tried `heatmap!`, but it leads to unshrink version and isn't helpful.